# android relative textview show hide without change other item position

Tags: android, xml

this is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/reveal_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logo" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.77">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/res"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/response" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="response" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/profile" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="my profile" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/badge_notification_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
                android:text="27"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_above="@id/noti"

                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/noti"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/notification" />





            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Notification" />




        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/req"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/req" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="add request" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logout" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="logout" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/help"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/help" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="help" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this the screenshot of result

[image]

the badge code its

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/badge_notification_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
                android:text="27"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_above="@id/noti"

                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
```

i add badge to the notification but its make notification icon and text of notification not in one line with other table 
did there are some thing to make badge relative and i can add it any where on xml code without change the other item position so now the problem this badge will set visible to false when its zero so the notification icon will go little above and when new notification come and set visible true  the notification icon will back down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by setting the visibility to INVISIBLE, not to GONE

according to Google documentation,
Set visibility: You can hide or show views using setVisibility(int).

**If you set it to INVISIBLE** 
This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

**If you set it to GONE** 
This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.